# Generate a csv and send to email

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv, php-5.3

I want to generate a csv file and send this to email, I tried like this :

```
function create_csv_string($data) {
// Open temp file pointer
if (!$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'w+')) return FALSE;
fputcsv($fp, array('Jour', 'Nombre 1', 'Nombre 2', 'Total'));
// Loop data and write to file pointer
foreach ($data as $line){
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
}
// Place stream pointer at beginning
rewind($fp);
// Return the data
return stream_get_contents($fp);

}
function send_csv_mail($csvData, $body, $to = 'myemail@gmail.com', $subject = 'Stats', $from = 'noreply@my.com') {
// This will provide plenty adequate entropy
$multipartSep = '-----'.md5(time()).'-----';
$headers = array(
    "From: $from",
    "Reply-To: $from",
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$multipartSep\""
);
// Make the attachment
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(create_csv_string($csvData)));
// Make the body of the message
$body = "--$multipartSep\r\n"
    . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed\r\n"
    . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n"
    . "\r\n"
    . "$body\r\n"
    . "--$multipartSep\r\n"
    . "Content-Type: text/csv\r\n"
    . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
    . "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"Stats-Report-" . date("F-j-Y") . ".csv\"\r\n"
    . "\r\n"
    . "$attachment\r\n"
    . "--$multipartSep--";
// Send the email, return the result
return @mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));
}
```

My array `$csvData` is like this :

```
(
[2015-07-07] => 20
[2015-07-08] => 48
[2015-07-09] => 42
[2015-07-10] => 94
[2015-07-11] => 0
[2015-07-12] => 0
[2015-07-13] => 6
[2015-07-14] => 0
)
```

I get the email with the `.csv` but this csv is empty with this column `array('Jour', 'Nombre 1', 'Nombre 2', 'Total')` wrote in one column. Can you help me please ? Thanks in advance.